# How to open a PDF file in browser using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying a test to see if I can open a PDF file in a directory on an Apache server. There is no .htaccess for the directory. When I execute the code I get a "Failed to load PDF document" error. The $filePath is fine. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
$filePath = '/home/xxx/public_html/xFiles/Reports/Test.pdf';
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    echo "The file $filePath exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filePath does not exist";
    die();
}
$filename="Test.pdf";

header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');
readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: you have output before headers, this is not allowed

Answer (score 3):

just don't echo anything before the headers and the pdf output.
i think that might just have broken your pdf-data.

```
$filePath = '/home/xxx/public_html/xFiles/Reports/Test.pdf';
if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
    echo "The file $filePath does not exist";
    die();
}
$filename="Test.pdf";

header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('content-Transfer-Encoding:binary');
header('Accept-Ranges:bytes');
readfile($filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks Max for your help. I had 2 problems, 1. as you stated. 2. I was running this from "php snippets" plugin on a web page. It works if I load it on the server as a php file. Thanks again for your kind assistance.